# How to write pseudocode to compute n!!(double factorial) recursively?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

```
n!!= 1*3*...*n, if n is odd.
n!!= 2*4*...*n, if n is even.
```

I've been trying, but I'm having a tough time starting this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
if n = 1, n!! = 1  
if n = 2, n!! = 2  
else n!! = n * (n-2)!!
```